# In JQuery 1.4.2 .ajax converts JSON wrong

Tags: jquery

My code worked fine in JQuery 1.3.2, but in 1.4.2 it seems to be broken. What it should get in the post is something like this:

```
?pks=108;pks=107
```

What I now get is:

```
?pks[]=108;pks[]=107;
```

When I trace this code through, the JSON object seems to be fine until it enters .ajax. Firebug, after the response is received, shows the post was:

```
Parameters  application/x-www-form-urlencoded
pks[]   108
pks[]   107
Source
pks%5B%5D=108&pks%5B%5D=107
```

Which is not what I got on JQuery 1.3.2. Where are those extra braces coming from?

Comment: Could you post your code please.

Comment: Your source line is wrong, which is where the brackets come from.  You may want to use something like fiddler to see what is actually being returned from the webserver.

Comment: As it turns out I had nothing wrong since it broke when I upgraded from jQuery 1.3.2 to 1.4.2. It seems that jQuery has changed its behavior, see answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JQuery 1.4 [released a change](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14) for **Nested param serialization**. From their site:

> jQuery 1.4 adds support for nested param serialization in jQuery.param, using the approach popularized by PHP, and supported by Ruby on Rails. For instance, {foo: ["bar", "baz"]} will be serialized as “foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz”.
>
> In jQuery 1.3, {foo: ["bar", "baz"]} was serialized as “foo=bar&foo=baz”. However, there was no way to encode a single-element Array using this approach. If you need the old behavior, you can turn it back on by setting the traditional Ajax setting (globally via `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional` or on a case-by-case basis via the traditional flag).

The `[]` brackets are normally used to indicate an array, and this appears to be what they are trying to make more obvious here I think (as your query-string could be read to see that one value is being overwritten by the other).

**Edit**:
I think you could probably follow their suggestion to use either:

```
// Globally set it to use the old 1.3.* way of doing things.
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

// Enables the 1.3.* way for a single Ajax request only
$.ajax({ data: stuff, traditional: true });
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that there was a change in how this was being done. I can easily solve the problem in my Django code by looking for:

    request.POST.get('pks[]')

instead of:

    request.POST.get('pks').

Django gives me the list properly. The only issue I see with this change is that the framework code is now dependent on the idiosyncratic behavior of the JavaScript toolkit, JQuery in this case.